# Tomcat v9.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem-- Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to run Tomcat v9.0 server in Eclipse with 2 jar files:

taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar

But I kept running into this error message: "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start." And error log indicates that it caused by `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\PM4\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)`

I doubled check my jar file paths and they are in the right location with the rest of the project:

- C:\Users\abdc\Desktop\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
  C:\Users\abdc\Desktop\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar

Any insight would be really appreciated. This is my error logs:

```
Jul 11, 2020 12:39:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext backgroundProcess
WARNING: Exception processing loader [WebappLoader[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PM4]]] background process
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\PM4\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\PM4\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:221)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
    ... 21 more

Jul 11, 2020 12:40:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext backgroundProcess
WARNING: Exception processing loader [WebappLoader[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PM4]]] background process
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\PM4\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\PM4\WEB-INF\lib\taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:221)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
    ... 21 more
```

This is my file directory:
[File directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptJ7G.png)

Comment: For the locations mentioned in the FileNotFoundExceptions, are the jars actually there? What options are you using with your Tomcat server? Is it actually v9.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong path,
U must paste your jar file in this path :

C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\PM4\WEB-INF\lib\

Comment: I wonder why that is the case... since my WebContent file is under my project file, and I had to go to C:\Users\abdc\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\  to create folders to match the error link path. But the issue was resolved! Thank you!!

Comment: That's why i dont use eclipse for my project.... Hehehehe